# How can I randomize all lines in a textfile without having to save them to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

In my project to create a neural network that trains off of chess positions, I downloaded 70 million games from database.lichess.org and extracted the positions of every move from every game and saved the won, lost, and drawn positions to different files.

I can pretty much start training my neural network now, but if I start training now the positions will be clumped together by game - for example the first 90 positions (of a 45 move game after every halfmove) would be from the same game. This means that almost a whole iteration of training will be heavily biased towards the result of a certain game.

The obvious solution is to randomize each line in the textfile, but the only way I know how to do this is like so:

```
import random as rand


def shuffle_lines(textfile_location):
    textfile_lines_list = []

    with open(textfile_location, "r") as textfile:

        for line in textfile.readlines():
            textfile_lines_list.append(line)

    rand.shuffle(textfile_lines_list)
    
    with open(textfile_location, "w") as textfile:
        textfile.truncate()
        
        for line in textfile_lines_list:
            textfile.write(line)
```

With the amount of data that I am shuffling (~70'000'000 games * 70 halfmoves = ~4'900'000'000 positions), I am worried that this will take a ton of time because I first have to copy every item from the textfile to a list, then shuffle the list, then copy the list back to the textfile.

Is there any more efficient way to do this, for example shuffling the textfile without copying to a list first?

Comment: The list doesn't have to be shuffled - you can randomly select lines from it unshuffled

Comment: @barny yes, that could work... I'd need to somehow remember which lines I have already accessed though, perhaps by storing a list with the indices of all the lines I have looked at already?

Comment: Why dont you split the dataset into a smaller subset of the dataset. This way you can randomly select the subset, load the subset into a variable, and the randomly select the lines you want to use.

Comment: @deecue that would work for the smaller subsets, but if I want to process all 70 million games it will take just as long as if I randomised it all at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit: Updated my answer to reflect @Maxijazz 's comment)

Instead of shuffling, here is an easier approach (here `n` is the number of lines in the current file):

Use `numpy.random.permutation(n-1)`. This will return an array containing a random permutation of integers [0,1...,n-1]. You can simply use these elements in sequential order to create a "shuffling" effect.

Comment: That kind of idea is something I will definitely go for. However, your proposed solution has some flaws: If we're regenerating whenever we gat a file I've already used, by the time we're down to the last 100'000 files it'll take forever to find them by randomly guessing. Probably a better solution would be to save a list of all natural numbers 0 -> n-1, and every time I need to access a line to randomly pick a number from the list and then delete it afterwards. That way it only needs to select a random index from the list and then readline(index).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But deleting an index from a list can take O(N) complexity, and repeated doing this takes extra time. Updated my answer to reflect your suggestion and this fact.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a different approach:

on neural networks, if you have a bias in the beginning of your training, there are usually 2 things to be done:

- increase batch size (less bias for each game in the batch)
- decrease or change the learning rate (smaller weight changes will occur in the beginning)